# H264 apparently doesn't work on Android browser

Tags: android, html, browser, video, format

At the beginning of a project with mobile videos, I tested h264 in an html5 player (video-js), and sent it to a friend to get it tested. It was working well un google browser for android.

I am now at the end of the project, and have sent the link to other people, just to be sure it really work.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working...

If you have an android mobile phone, could you test it in the google browser?
http://daviddarx.com/stuffs/work/mjf_video_exemples/index.html (the video of the bottom is the html one)

H264 should work on both IOS and android browsers, isn't it?
If else, could you give me more correct indications about formats for these both platforms?

Thank you in advance!
David

Comment: Please fix your Content-type HTTP header.

Answer (score 1):

Please fix your content type header:

```
huiske-imac:tmp moo$ wget -S http://daviddarx.com/stuffs/work/videos/mjf_1500.mp4
--2011-09-20 16:21:54--  http://daviddarx.com/stuffs/work/videos/mjf_1500.mp4
Resolving daviddarx.com (daviddarx.com)... 80.74.154.187
Connecting to daviddarx.com (daviddarx.com)|80.74.154.187|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Tue, 20 Sep 2011 13:21:54 GMT
  Server: Apache/2.0.52 (CentOS)
  Last-Modified: Mon, 08 Aug 2011 11:10:35 GMT
  ETag: "17440f9-231e307-7f0920c0"
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
  Content-Length: 36823815
  Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=10
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Content-Type: text/plain
Length: 36823815 (35M) [text/plain]
Saving to: `mjf_1500.mp4'
```

Comment: Hi Mikko, thank you for your answer, but I don't understand what you're asking me to change? 
Is it something to change in the html page, or in the video file itself? Will this modification solve the problem? Thank you for your help! 
DAvid

Comment: Content-Type: text/plain <-- your web server is misconfigured to server video files as text files. You need to learn about HTTP protocol and its Content-type header. There might be other issues, but this is the most obvious one.